# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: project_id when calling to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wrote a below query class, which is throwing a missing attribute error which I didn't put in the select method anywhere. Any idea from where this error might be coming? Why `project_id` is being searched in the `to_json` method.

```
class WorkitemPriceResearchPresenter
  def initialize(company)
    @company = company
  end

  def query
    @workitems ||= \
      @company
        .workitems
        .joins(
          :workitem_category,
          :workitem_status,
          { project: [:shipyard, {vessel: :vessel_category}] }, 
        )
        .select <<-EOS
          workitems.id as id,
          projects.sequential_id as sequential_id,
          vessels.name as vessel_name,
          vessel_categories.code as vessel_category,
          shipyards.name as shipyard,
          workitems.item_code as item_code,
          workitems.description as description,
          workitems.unit as unit,
          workitems.price_cents as price_cents,
          workitems.currency as currency,
          workitems.quantity as quantity,
          workitem_statuses.name as status,
          workitems.discount as discount,
          DATE_PART('year', projects.scheduled_from::date) as scheduled_from_year,
          projects.scheduled_from as scheduled_from,
          DATE_PART('year', projects.scheduled_to::date) as scheduled_to_year,
          projects.scheduled_to as scheduled_to,
          workitem_categories.name as Category
        EOS
  end

  def as_json
    query.to_json
  end
end
```

Error is:

```
pry(main)> WorkitemPriceResearchPresenter.new(company).query.as_json
  Workitem Load (33.7ms)  SELECT           workitems.id as id,
          projects.sequential_id as sequential_id,
          vessels.name as vessel_name,
          vessel_categories.code as vessel_category,
          shipyards.name as shipyard,
          workitems.item_code as item_code,
          workitems.description as description,
          workitems.unit as unit,
          workitems.price_cents as price_cents,
          workitems.currency as currency,
          workitems.quantity as quantity,
          workitem_statuses.name as status,
          workitems.discount as discount,
          DATE_PART('year', projects.scheduled_from::date) as scheduled_from_year,
          projects.scheduled_from as scheduled_from,
          DATE_PART('year', projects.scheduled_to::date) as scheduled_to_year,
          projects.scheduled_to as scheduled_to,
          workitem_categories.name as Category
 FROM "workitems" INNER JOIN "workitem_categories" ON "workitem_categories"."id" = "workitems"."workitem_category_id" INNER JOIN "workitem_statuses" ON "workitem_statuses"."id" = "workitems"."workitem_status_id" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."id" = "workitems"."project_id" AND "projects"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "shipyards" ON "shipyards"."id" = "projects"."shipyard_id" AND "shipyards"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "vessels" ON "vessels"."id" = "projects"."vessel_id" AND "vessels"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "vessel_categories" ON "vessel_categories"."id" = "vessels"."vessel_category_id" AND "vessel_categories"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "workitems"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "workitems"."company_id" = $1  [["company_id", "c61e4368-1a60-464b-8002-9da31bf301e5"]]
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: project_id
from /Users/ar/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:93:in `block in _read_attribute'
```

Let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are joining workitems with project, your workitems is supposed to have a project_id attribute in order to join the tables. But it looks like you do not have such column, so you are getting this error.

Comment: I have that column present in the table.. I just renamed `shipyards.name as shipyard` to `shipyards.name as shipyard_name`. It solved the issue.  very strange is that what was wrong with just `shipyard` as alias name.